# Windows Authentication of Web API when using a Proxy/Pass through URL

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-401, ghostlab

I am trying to get a tool for web testing setup (GhostLab).  It seems to be close to working, but I am getting a 401 (Unauthorized) for my Web API requests.

My Web API service is hosted in IIS and uses HTTPS.  It authenticates using Windows Authentication.

When I connect normally this is the URL:

Access is denied due to invalid credentials

> https://MyServer/MyService/Service/breeze/Controller/Metadata

And that works great.

When I try to do it via GhostLab it seems to be using this URL:

> http://10.92.1.67:8005/https://MyServer/MyService/Service/breeze/Controller/Metadata

And then I get the 401 error.

I get that this is an HTTPS related issue.  But I am at a loss for how to configure things to allow it to work.

**Can I update IIS to be more permissive?**  (on my test server only of course)

**Or is there a something in my service config I need to change?**

Do I need to change authentication to be more than just Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to enable Anonymous Authentication.  Not ideal, but it works for testing.